# The number of binary strings of length $n$ with no three consecutive ones

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am becoming more familiar with proving sequences that are given in a problem, though I am not familiar with how to actually define a sequence. More specifically, I am dealing mostly with binary numbers and tiling problems, though again, most of what I have deslt with have been proofs, not trying to define a sequence.

The particular problem that has been frustrating me for the past few days is this:

- *Define a sequence {$s_n$} by recursion such that there are s_n different sequences of 0's and 1’s of length n that do not contain three consecutive 1's.*

I know the answer is $s_n = s_{n−1} + s_{n−2} + s_{n−3}$ but I don't understand why. I have tried listing the possible values for n:

- n = 1 has 2 posibilities (0, 1)
- n = 2 has 4 posibilities (00, 01, 10, 11)
- n = 3 has 7 posibilities (000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, not including 111)
- etc.

I know this problems also relates to Fibonacci's sequence in that each number in the sequence builds off of the previous one(s), though at this point, I don't know where to continue. Could someone please explain the steps to get to $s_n = s_{n−1} + s_{n−2} + s_{n−3}$?

Comment: Hi Alana, welcome.  Please take a look at this [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to make your formulas prettier (just put dollar signs around the expressions.)

Comment: Many equivalent expressions [here](https://oeis.org/A000073)

Answer (score 2):

A sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s with no three consecutive $1$'s, of length $n>3$, has a form of $s0$, or $s01$, or $s011$, where $s$ is again a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s with no three consecutive $1$'s (of length $n-1$, $n-2$ or $n-3$, respectively). And any such $s$ results in a valid sequence; we have one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: That makes sense, though what are / how do you find the base cases?

Comment: Aren't these listed in the text of your question? (Or what else do you mean?)