# Finding the closed form or tight bound for the number of binary strings with $k$ ones or $k$ zeros and no three consecutive ones

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, closed-form, upper-lower-bounds

I have been investigating the problem of counting the number of binary strings of length $n$ such that it has no three consecutive $1$'s, but also either has exactly $k$ $1$'s or exactly $k$ $0$'s where $k$ is a positive integer between $1$ and $n$ (inclusive).
For example, if $n = 4$ and $k = 3$, then there are six valid such binary strings: $0001$, $0010$, $0100$, $1000$, $1011$, and $1101$.

From my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616129/number-of-binary-strings-with-k-ones-or-k-zeros-and-no-three-consecutive-one), we defined $F(p,q)$ as the number of binary strings with no three consecutive 1's with exactly $p$ $1$'s and $q$ $0$'s. From the [answer by Markus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4617173/1134332) there, we get the following formula for counting the desired binary strings with exactly $k$ $1$'s:

$$
F(k,n-k) = \sum_{j=0}^{\min(n-k+1, \lfloor k/2 \rfloor)} {n-k+1 \choose j}{n-k+1-j \choose k-2j}
$$

Similarly, we have the formula for $F(n-k,k)$ to count the desired binary strings with exactly $k$ $0$'s.

$$
F(n-k,k) = \sum_{j=0}^{\min(k+1,\lfloor (n-k)/2 \rfloor)} {k+1 \choose j}{k+1-j \choose n-k-2j}
$$

We can add the two results at the end to get our final answer (i.e., $F(k,n-k) + F(n-k,k)$).

What I am curious about now is, can we get the closed form of these two formulas?
Or at least, a non-trivial asymptotic lower bound?
It is obvious that $F(k,n-k) + F(n-k,k) = \Omega(n)$ as the number of solutions for $k = 1$ is at least $n$.
Moreover, is it possible to obtain an asymptotic upper bound tighter than $O(2^n)$?
Here $2^n$ is the number of binary strings of length $n$ with no restriction.

Here is what I have found so far:

1. The spreadsheet that shows the number of solutions for $n \leq 100, 1 \leq k \leq n$ can be viewed [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AuTf8xkpvrRizO2iv-KKHwFRQtbKO-YpRq1pwbefx08/edit?usp=sharing).
2. Based on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635934/the-number-of-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-no-three-consecutive-ones), the number of binary strings of length $n$ with no occurrence of "$111$" and no other restrictions follows the tribonacci sequence but shifted forward by two terms.
   An explicit formula for calculating the $n$-th tribonacci number is available [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html).
   Then, we can derive the asymptotic upper bound for this case to be $O((p_{+} + p_{-} + 1)^{n})$ where $p_\pm = \sqrt[3]{19\pm 3 \sqrt{33}}$ or roughly $O(1.8392^n)$.
   Since this case allows any number of $1$'s or $0$'s, it basically sums up the solutions for $k = 1, 2, \dots n$ in our problem.
   Therefore, this upper bound also applies to our problem.
   However, this does not consider the value $k$ in our original expression.
3. For even $n$ with $k = \frac{n}{2}$, the number of solutions follows the sequence $2, 6, 16, 45, 126, 357, \dots$ which is available in the OEIS.
   Using an approximation by Vaclav Kotesovec there, we get $F(\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2}) = O(3^{\frac{n}{2}})$ or roughly $O(1.732^n)$.
   I checked with a program for $n \leq 5000$, the asymptotic upper bound seems to also apply for odd $n$ (with $k = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)$.
   As $k = \frac{n}{2}$ doesn't always give the peak value for $F$, then a tight asymptotic upper bound for general $k$ is somewhere between $O(3^{\frac{n}{2}})$ and $O(1.8392^n)$.

I would appreciate any ideas or suggestions to improve or verify these bounds, and I am open to alternative solutions that may provide more accurate estimates for the problem.
Additionally, final bounds that include the variable $k$ would be great if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you say "this upper bound might also apply to our problem"? Your strings form a subset of the strings with no three consecutive $1$s, so any upper bound on that superset is necessarily also a bound for your subset, no?

Comment: @joriki I think OP should write, ".. this upper bound also applies to our problem", but $O(1.8392^n)$ is not tight enough for this problem.

Comment: My mistake, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the post.

Comment: If you fix $k$, once $n > 3k + 2$ such strings cannot have only $k$ 0s, so must have exactly $k$ 1s, so the count is given by $$\sum_{i = \lceil k/2 \rceil}^k \binom{n - k - 1}{i},$$ (where $i$ is the number of strings of 1s) in particular $\Theta(n^k)$.